# How to find average duration of time number of times a value occurs in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where I have one row per store. Columns B-K are dates. Each cell under those columns are tracking the number of deliveries made on that day. Some cells have a value of 0, indicating that on that day, the store took a day off from performing deliveries. I want to find the avg. duration of time off per store. I made an example of the desired output in the attached image. For Store 1, he had two days in a row of 0 deliveries, and then a few days later, one more day with 0 deliveries. So his avg. time off duration is 1.5. How can I do this?

[image]

I've tried a number of functions but none are working

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(rng,B2:K2,frq,FREQUENCY(IF(rng=0,COLUMN(rng)),IF(rng<>0,COLUMN(rng))),AVERAGE(FILTER(frq,frq<>0)))
```

[image]

Or this one that will spill

```
=BYROW(B2:K4,LAMBDA(rng,LET(frq,FREQUENCY(IF(rng=0,COLUMN(rng)),IF(rng<>0,COLUMN(rng))),AVERAGE(FILTER(frq,frq<>0)))))
```